# How can I setup an NFS share using a GUI?

Tags: nfs, sharing

Is there a GUI for selecting which folders are shared via NFS?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/554630/gui-to-mount-nfs-folder

Comment: @rubo77 - check related http://superuser.com/questions/636562/nfs-server-client-administration-of-multiple-machines-through-a-gui , there is a bit about `webmin` there (almost, but not quite, a GUI)

Comment: Just for the unlucky fact, that there is no GUI: it is not so hard to configure it on the console: http://tecadmin.net/how-to-configure-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a GUI for samba shares, but AFAIK there is none for nfs at this time. However, there is a request at [brainstorm](https://web.archive.org/web/20100624234331/http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/2982) about this issue. Maybe you can go there and support this issue.

Comment: Is this still the case that there is no GUI? (Brainstorm is dead, so I replaced the link with the archived version on archive.org)

Answer (score 2):

There is an app for Ubuntu :

[**Simple NFS GUI**](https://github.com/Philippe734/Simple.NFS.GUI)

Available on Github

[image: Capture]